# How to iterate element in a method after converting to List?

Tags: java, arrays, spring, list, java-stream

I have the following endpoint:

```
public void save(@Valid @RequestBody SaveRequest request) {
    demoService.save(request);
}
```

In `SaveRequest`, I pass a single `productUuid` as shown below.

```
@Data
public class SaveRequest {

    private UUID productUuid;

    private DetailsRequest detailsRequest;
}
```

Here is my service method:

```
public void save(final SaveRequest request) {
    detailService.getDetails(request.getProductUuid());

    // code omitted
}
```

What I want to do is; I just want to pass `productUuid` as a list instead of single element. `private List<UUID> productUuid;`

I thought that I can call the service method for each `productUuid` in the `SaveRequest`, instead of modifying the service method by using a similar approach to the following. Then I call this methıd from the Controller instead of the `save` methof of the service.

```
public void saveList(final SaveRequest request) {
    request.getProductUuidList().stream()
        .map(this::save)
        .collect(Collectors.toList());
}
```

But I could not use it. So, how should I fix this issue? If it is good approach to use `saveList` methood and call `save` method for each `productUuid` in the `SaveRequest`, it may be better to use it without changing the `save` method.

Comment: `demoService.save()` takes a `SaveRequest`. With `request.getProductUuidList().stream().map(this::save)` you are passing it a `UUID` (assuming that `request.getProductUuidList()` is a `List<UUID>`). Maybe the way to handle multiple products is to modify the service method.

Comment: Yes, that's the problem exactly. Normally it is not too difficult, but as I have to pass `request` according to each element of the List in that `request`, I failed. Any idea?

Comment: You are using `collect(Collectors.toList())`. What exactly do you want to collect?

Comment: No need to collect, you may omit it. Just need to call the `save` method multiple times based on the list. In this scene, I think I should need to use an index in the stream. Is that true? ANd what is your suggestion?

Comment: instead of `stream.map.collect` try `forEach` to pass the elements to a consumer.

Comment: @thinkgruen I tried it, not fixed. Why do not you post your suggestion as an answer with containing full lines?

Comment: **What about using a for loop and save each element in the list in `save` method?**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Updating the answer now. You were correct with your last answer, because Streams usually expect you to do something with what is inside (in your case UUIDs).

If you don't want to have a Consumer for UUIDs, you can use a for loop:

```
public void saveList(final SaveRequest request) {
  for (UUID uuid: request.getProductUuidList()) {
    save(request);
  }
}
```

and if you need the UUID that is currently being iterated, change the save method to accept a UUID as an argument

```
public void saveList(final SaveRequest request) {
  for (UUID uuid: request.getProductUuidList()) {
    save(uuid, request);
  }
}
```

As you can see, the last method has a consumer for UUIDs now, so it can also be done using streams:

```
public void saveList(final SaveRequest request) {
  request.getProductUuidList().stream().forEach(
    uuid -> save(uuid, request);
  )
}
```

Using `stream()` here is optional, but can provide you with helpful features, such as filters.

Comment: Good points, thanks for helping. I also thought to use `List<SaveRequest>`, but it does not fix the ``List<UUID> productUuid` in the request. Because the current method accepts `SaveRequest` and there is not a list of `UUID` (it is single element).

Comment: Things that are still unclear to me
 `detailService.getDetails(request.getProductUuid());` is called, but never assigned to anything. Also, I think     `detailService.getDetails(request.getDetailsRequest());` would be clearer.

Also: if you don't have multiple elements anywhere in the request, how do you want the service to execute something multiple times? you would need to do at least _some_ changes to your model before you can proceed.

Comment: `SaveRequest` includes `List<UUID> productUuid;` and I want to pass `SaveRequest` multiple times to the `save` method. If there are 5 elements in the `List<UUID> productUuid;` then I need to pass `SaveRequest` to teh `save` methof 5 times.

Comment: got it. i'm aiming to update my answer accordingly.

Comment: Thanks a lot, passing uuid is the thing that I tried and decided before reading your answer. Voted up.

Comment: On the other hand, what is the purpose of `stream()` and its effect at here?

Comment: In your scenario a stream could be helpful if you had some sort of filter logic or want to do transformations on whatever is inside the stream. For example imagine you had some duplicate UUIDs in the request. You could do `stream().distinct().forEach(...)`. If you just want to iterate over each elements, you can pick `forEach` without the Stream.